# can you schedule the start and stop time of copying in wget?

Tags: wget, schedule

Hi there I'm new here in the forum and very new using tools for Linux. Actually I'm tasked to learn about `wget`. I already know a few though I'm trying to find out if there is a syntax to use to schedule the start and stop time of the copying or downloading, please help thanks!

Comment: What are you going to do? `wget` doesn't have a scheduling mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

`wget` itself doesn't have scheduling properties, but as you are using Linux then you probably have to take a look for `cron`.

Cron is a time-based job scheduler in Linux, used to schedule jobs (commands or shell scripts) to run periodically at fixed times, dates, or intervals.

To add a job to cron scheduler as normal user run the command:

```
crontab -e
```

else if you want to schedule a job for root:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

Linux Crontab Format

```
MIN HOUR DOM MON DOW CMD

Field      Description       Allowed Value

MIN        Minute field        0 to 59
HOUR       Hour field          0 to 23
DOM        Day of Month        1-31
MON        Month field         1-12
DOW        Day Of Week         0-6
CMD        Command             Any command to be executed.
```

For example:

Run the wget in a specific time let's say in 15july 8:20 AM

then the cron entry would be like:

```
20 08 15 07 * wget URL://
```

Take  a look at:

- `man cron`
- `man crontab`
- `man 5 crontab`
- http://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference
- https://askubuntu.com/a/630124/150504

Now by the time you want to stop wget you have also to add another cron entry using `pkill` command: let's say I want to stop wget at  15july 10:30 PM then add this entry to cron:

```
30 22 15 07 * pkill wget
```

To resume again a broken `wget` download, you can use the `-c` or `--continue` option in wget.

```
wget -c URL://
wget --continue URL://
```

`man wget`

```
-c
   --continue
       Continue getting a partially-downloaded file.  This is useful when
       you want to finish up a download started by a previous instance of
       Wget, or by another program.
```

Comment: Now how would you stop `wget`?

Comment: use pkill in cron to kill wget

Comment: Add that to the answer and complete it! Also mention how you can continue downloads using `wget`.

Comment: So Why downvoting?!

Comment: @muru ok i'll edit the answer adding the needed info

Comment: I'm pretty sure I upvoted your post.

Comment: @muru Thanks, I know not you but just I'm wondering why such answer would be downvoted!!!

Comment: Does `wget` supports to split download link to parts? e.g. Downloading 1TB in 2 HDD 500GB each

Answer (score 0):

The usual linux/unix way to do this would be to use another system utility to schedule wget activity: cron.

See

```
man 5 crontab
man cron
```

and

```
man crontab
```